# Can I use Caddy in Rocket.Chat snap for free?

Tags: apache-2.0

I need to enable SSL for Rocket.Chat. [Here](https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/configuring-ssl-reverse-proxy/#running-behind-a-caddy-reverse-proxy-with-free-ssl) I found that I can do it with Caddy. I have never used Caddy before. Personal license [here](https://caddyserver.com/products/licenses) says Caddy is free only for non-commercial use. And Caddy has open source too under Apache License 2.0 [here](https://github.com/mholt/caddy/blob/master/LICENSE.txt).

I am not sure whether commercial license is needed for running Rocket.Chat behind a Caddy Reverse Proxy. Please point out if it is too naive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That website makes it very clear that the Apache license only applies to the source code, not to the official binaries on the Caddy download page. We can't tell you whether the personal license of the official binaries would fit your use case.

The Apache license does not prohibit you from using the software commercially. You may run the software for any purpose. To obtain Caddy under the Apache license, compile the software yourself or obtain binaries from some other provider (for example, the “release” tab on GitHub).